# When I Place Order Than The Error Ocuure "An error occurred on the server. Please try to place the order again." in Magento2

Tags: magento2, error, place-order

I have try the order placed but showing this error

> here i attach the link what was actuall problem face in magento 2

[http://prntscr.com/rd9oeq][1]

Comment: For finding the exact issue please check log in var/log folder or also check-in console network response.it may help you to find exact issue that why it's happening.

Answer (score 0):

You try this link may be help you.

you change the savePaymentInformationAndPlaceOrder() function and see

And Now you get the actual error and you should find the full exception in the exception.log file

**https://www.magebay.com/forum/show-error-checkout-magento-2-error-occurred-server-please-try/**